# How can I send the same audio output to two audio devices?

Tags: windows, linux, audio, mixer, asio

Say I have 2 speakers connected to 2 different sound cards. Under Windows, is it possible to have some sort of virtual device that would forward an audio stream to both sound cards? If this can't be easily done under Windows, a solution for Linux is also fine.

Alternatively, if the 2 speakers are connected to different channels of a sound card, is there any vendor-independent way to duplicate audio to both channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux, PulseAudio can send [output to multiple audio devices](http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/Modules#module-combine).  I have no clue about Windows, sorry.